# How to find mean in kmeans in single shot using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a function:

```
def update(points, closest, centroids):
    return np.array([points[closest==k].mean(axis=0) for k in range(centroids.shape[0])])
```

It basically the update of centroids step in kmeans algorithm.
Basically, points is a matrix, closest is an assignment of a point to a cluster..

and then all i am doing is finding the new mean based on points in a cluster..

but I was wondering if i can get rid of that for loop?
which is if i can find the cluster mean in one shot?

Comment: I've got a tip on this code. You could exchange it for a generator, exchanging the np.array([points.. , .. shape[0])]) for np.array(points.. , .. shape[0])), removing some meaningless memory overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach based on [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
c = np.bincount(closest,minlength=centroids.shape[0])
mask = c != 0
pts_grp = points[closest.argsort()]
cut_idx = np.append(0,c[mask].cumsum()[:-1])
out = np.full((centroids.shape[0],points.shape[1]),np.nan)
out[mask] = np.add.reduceat(pts_grp,cut_idx,axis=0)/c[mask,None].astype(float)
```